# How to trigger a Jenkins pipeline only when a pull request is made from a specific branch in GitHub?

Tags: git, jenkins, testing, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Our team changed the branching strategy and that requires me to change the Jenkins settings. There is a main **"master"** branch and a **"dev"** branch.

The devs will make their individual discrete pull requests (PRs) to the **dev** which will trigger some unit tests on GitHub Actions, but when a PR is made from the **"dev"** branch to the main **"master"** branch a Jenkins pipeline should be triggered.

As I have currently configured the process, the Jenkins pipeline is triggered on every single pull request, regardless of the branch but what I am trying to do is only trigger the Jenkins pipeline every time a PR is made specifically the from **"dev"** branch to the **"master"** branch.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you can use several strategies.

First: you may want to have a naming convention in place for the branches that are opened against `dev` branch and plan to be eventually merged there. You can then set up the pipeline to filter based on the match between a branch name and the naming convention. Note that this will trigger a job on a branch, as opposed to on PR.

Second: you may want to fire a pipeline anyway on every PR, find out the destination branch, and if it does not fit your configuration, bail out early and abort the build.

In a somewhat similar situation, we use the second approach.